# How to get all the entities that do not have a given attribute?

Tags: sparql

I need to formulate a SPARQL query that returns me all entities that have a given number of values for a given attribute. For example, I want to have all the countries that border with exactly two other countries.

I also might want to find all countries that do not border with any other country (so, the number of values of the attribute "hasBorderWith" is equal to zero. In this context, it is not clear to me if there is a difference between the following two cases:

1. An entity has zero values for the given attribute.
2. An entity does not have the given entity.

For example, I can imagine that a country that does not have borders with other country does not have "hasBorderWith" attribute. Will it cause a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of questions embedded here.  To find countries bordered by exactly two countries, you'd need to group by the country match and get the count.  Then use `HAVING`, which is executed after the aggregate has been calculated to filter by the count criteria:

```
SELECT ?country (count(?bordered) AS ?borderCount)
WHERE {
   ?country a :Country .
   ?country :hasBorderWith ?bordered
}  GROUP BY ?country
   HAVING (?borderCount = 2)
```

For the second question, I don't see a difference between 0 and no property, and this can be computed with a negation query:

```
SELECT ?country
WHERE {
   ?country a :Country .
   FILTER NOT EXISTS {
      ?country :hasBorderWith ?x
   }
 }
```

**EDIT: to find a count of 0**

Per the questions and @ASKW's suggestion, the following would get a count of 0 if there are no `hasBorderWith` properties:

```
SELECT ?country (count(?bordered) AS ?borderCount)
WHERE {
   ?country a :Country .
   OPTIONAL {
      ?country :hasBorderWith ?bordered
   }
}  GROUP BY ?country
   HAVING (?borderCount = 0)
```

The `OPTIONAL` clause allows the match to occur, but will not contribute to the `count(?bordered)` aggregate if `?bordered` is not bound, hence members of `:Country` without a `:hasBorderWith` property will get a count of 0.

Comment: if there is not difference between 0 values and no property, would it be possible in you first example to replace 2 by 0 and get the same result as returned by your second example?

Comment: The `GROUP BY` works only on matches, even if the `hasBorderWith` clause uses `OPTIONAL`, so no, it's not possible to get a 0 result with the first query.

Comment: @scotthenninger Are you sure? Please try an example on DBpedia: http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT+%3Fcountry+%28count%28%3Fo%29+AS+%3FoCount%29%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A+++%3Fcountry+a+dbo%3ACountry+.%0D%0A+++optional%7B%3Fcountry+dbo%3AbirthPlace+%3Fo%7D%0D%0A%7D++GROUP+BY+%3Fcountry%0D%0Aorder+by+DESC%28%3FoCount%29%0D%0A

Comment: It returns countries with the number of birth dates assigned to it.

Comment: In hindsight, my error was obvious, thanks for catching it @ASKW.